# .append() function not working inside a class in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I was writing Pygame basic fluid simulation when I got the error:
`IndexError: list index out of range`
And I was able to trace it to lines 53 and 54, that the .append() function was not appending new items, and then I found out that what I was passing in does not exist??? I printed what I was passing in the function and it didn't print out anything, I suspect that when I pass in the list of particles, it does not pass in somehow...
Also if someone knows if my code on collision will work, please tell me how you'd fix it.

```
import pygame, random, math

# Pygame vars
WIDTH = 750
HEIGHT = 750
FPS = 60

# Pygame init
pygame.init()
SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Program")

# Colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
CYAN = (0, 255, 255)
PINK = (255, 0, 255)

# Game vars
GRAVITY = 0.918
amt_white_particles = 100
amt_red_particles = 50
amt_green_particles = 10
collision_check_depth = 5
distance_to_ignore = 3

# Functions


# Classes
class Particle:
    def __init__(self, start_x, start_y, size, color):
        self.start_x = start_x
        self.start_y = start_y
        self.x, self.y = self.start_x, self.start_y
        self.dx, self.dy = [], []
        self.x_speed, self.y_speed = 0, 0
        self.size = size
        self.color = color
        self.mass = 1

    def check_collisions(self, particles_list):
        for i in range(len(particles_list)):
            if self.x < self.x + distance_to_ignore * (
                (self.size + particles_list[i].size) / 2
            ):
                continue

            self.dx.append(self.x - particles_list[i].x)
            self.dy.append(self.y - particles_list[i].y)
            distance = math.sqrt(self.dx[-1] ** 2 + self.dy[-1] ** 2)

            if distance < (self.size + particles_list[i].size) / 2:
                return ((self.size + particles_list[i].size) / 2) - distance
            else:
                return 0

    def move_if_colliding(self, overlap, particles_list):
        for i in range(len(particles_list)):
            dot_product = (particles_list[i].x - self.x) * (
                particles_list[i].y - self.y
            )
            angle = (
                math.acos(dot_product / (overlap * self.dx[i])) / (2 * math.pi) * 360
            )

            self.x += overlap * math.cos(angle)
            self.y += overlap * math.sin(angle)

    def start(self, particles):
        if self.y + self.size > HEIGHT:
            self.y_speed = 0
            self.gravity_temp = 0
            self.y = HEIGHT - self.size
        else:
            self.gravity_temp = GRAVITY

        self.y_speed += self.gravity_temp
        self.y += self.y_speed

        for _ in range(collision_check_depth):
            self.overlap = self.check_collisions(particles)
            self.move_if_colliding(self.overlap, particles)

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(
            SCREEN,
            self.color,
            (self.x - (self.size / WIDTH), self.y - (self.size / WIDTH)),
            self.size,
        )


def main():
    running = True
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    # Define objects here
    particles = []

    for _ in range(amt_white_particles):
        particles.append(
            Particle(random.randint(0, WIDTH), random.randint(0, HEIGHT), 5, WHITE)
        )
    for _ in range(amt_red_particles):
        particles.append(
            Particle(random.randint(0, WIDTH), random.randint(0, HEIGHT), 7, RED)
        )
    for _ in range(amt_green_particles):
        particles.append(
            Particle(random.randint(0, WIDTH), random.randint(0, HEIGHT), 10, GREEN)
        )

    # Event loop
    while running:
        clock.tick(FPS)

        # Event listener
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

        # Draw
        SCREEN.fill(BLACK)

        for i in range(len(particles)):
            particles[i].draw()

        # Write custom script here
        for i in range(len(particles)):
            particles[i].start(particles)

        # Update screen
        pygame.display.flip()

    pygame.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Anyone help me please
Thx if you do

//////////////////////////////

Expecting:
A list of all dx and dy values

Tried:
Traced it back and found it could have been the parameters to the function move_if_colliding()

//////////////////////////////
Full Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\ricob\Desktop\Programming\python\2d-fluid-sim\main.py", line 144, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\Users\ricob\Desktop\Programming\python\2d-fluid-sim\main.py", line 135, in main
    particles[i].start(particles)
  File "c:\Users\ricob\Desktop\Programming\python\2d-fluid-sim\main.py", line 87, in start
    self.move_if_colliding(self.overlap, particles)
  File "c:\Users\ricob\Desktop\Programming\python\2d-fluid-sim\main.py", line 68, in move_if_colliding
    math.acos(dot_product / (overlap * self.dx[i])) / (2 * math.pi) * 360
                                       ~~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: We would need to see the full traceback message to have any idea where to start looking for the problem.

Comment: Ok, I updated the post so it has the full traceback message.

Answer (score 1):

The `move_if_colliding` method, where you exception is occurring appears to expect the `self.dx` list to have at least as many items in it as there are particles in `particles_list`. But that assumption doesn't seem well founded.

When you `.append()` items into the `dx` list in `check_collisions`, you'll only ever add at most one item per call. That's because you always exit your loop over the particles after appending. There's an `if`/`else`, but both branches `return` something. And since there's another `if` above the append that can `continue` the loop without doing anything, you might skip all the particles, and not append at all (presumably there are no collisions at all in that case, though I don't fully understand all of the code).

Without a better understanding of your logic, I'm not sure I can really recommend a fix... Maybe you need to be putting the values you currently `return` from `check_collision` into a list that you return after the loop ends, so you can have more than one? Then you could iterate over that list and the `dx` list and be confident they are the same length.

Answer (score 0):

well, i could not get, where actually the error is, but i could make it run: change the function move_if_colliding to:

```
def move_if_colliding(self, overlap, particles_list):
        for i in range(len(particles_list)):
            dot_product = (particles_list[i].x - self.x) * (
                particles_list[i].y - self.y
            )
            if i in self.dx:
                angle = (
                    math.acos(dot_product / (overlap * self.dx[i])) / (2 * math.pi) * 360
                )

                self.x += overlap * math.cos(angle)
                self.y += overlap * math.sin(angle)
```

Comment: It's working, thx!